# How do I use the mysql cookbook?

Tags: mysql, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I'm trying to use the latest version of the mysql cookbook in the Chef Supermarket:

https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/mysql

(8.3.1)

I've added it as a wrapper cookbook and created a small recipe I'm trying to spin up in Test Ktichen:

```
include_recipe 'mysql'

mysql_service 'foo' do
  port '3306'
  version '5.7'
  initial_root_password 'change me'
  action [:create, :start]
end

mysql_config 'logging' do
  instance 'instance-1'
  source 'my.cnf.erb'
  action :create
  notifies :restart, 'mysql_service[instance-1]'
end
```

This quickly fails on converge with:

```
could not find recipe default for cookbook mysql
```

The depends 'mysql' is in the cookbook metadata.rb.

I've seen some posts that say this cookbook has undergone major refactoring... but  I still don't have a clue as how to actually use it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `include_recipe` method is used to call the specified recipe. If no recipe given, for example, `include_recipe '<cookbook_name>'`, it will call the default recipe, i.e., default.rb.

https://docs.chef.io/recipes.html#include-recipes

In your case, the `mysql` is a base cookbook and only have libraries and resources to be used in Wrapper cookbook. Therefore, you can call resources like `mysql_config` but `include_recipe` will fail because there is no recipe in that cookbook.

https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/mysql

Comment: I'm trying to provision a server with a Chef project that relied on an older version of the mysql cookbook (5.6.3). As this particular version is not compatible with anything newer that Ubuntu 14.04, I tried updating to the latest version (8.5.1) which lead to the same error.I understand that the mysql cookbook no longer provides recipes and is supposed to be a library only cookbook but it's really not clear how I'm supposed to edit the code to do what the older version did. Is there any other cookbook built on top of this one to simply install mysql client and server?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the include_recipe, just the other bits.